MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent I don't want make copy of image to gallery
I made an Android program for take document images with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE but I don't want make a copy to the gallery. I tested on Android 9/12/13/14. On 9/13/14 doesn't make a copy immediately. But on 12 I can't get this to work. Please help me.
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String =
            SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir =
            getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",  /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        )

        stored.imageFilePath = image.absolutePath
        return image
    }

    private fun takeAPicture() {
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

            val author = "${packageName}.provider"
            try {
                val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, author, photoFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(
                    MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    photoURI
                )
                cameraIntent.putExtra("saveToGallery", false)
                activityTakePictreLauncher.launch(cameraIntent)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", ex.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }

The files_path.xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/hu.infokristaly.docustorepictureapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>

I neked solution similar to cameraIntent.putExtra("saveToGallery", false)
